# Why boolean output turns to numerical output once I create a loop?

Tags: python, loops, boolean, scikit-image

I am using `skiimage` library, I got it works correctly for different input files data.

Here the code that is working:

To explain it briefly, `alpha_time` is a level set function structured as `[time,x,y,z]`, so `alpha_time[0,:,:,:]` is the level set function at `time = 0`.

```py
gaz0  = alpha_0[0,:,:,:] >= 0
labels_gaz0 = measure.label(gaz0)
props_gaz0 = measure.regionprops_table(labels_gaz0,properties 
 ['label','area'])
df0 = pandas.DataFrame(props_gaz0)
```

This code works correctly.

Now, rather than repeating it each time, I create a `for loop` to loop over time. I started with this line (let's say I have 10 files, let's say that the shape of `gaz0` was `(11,12,13)`:

```py
gaz = numpy.zeros(time,11,12,13)
for counter in range(0,10):
    gaz[counter,:,:,:] = alpha_time[counter,:,:,:] >=0
```

I did not have an error output, however when I do `print(gaz[counter,:,:,:]` I have a numerical matrix, ....
and when I do `print(gaz0)` I have a boolean output `True` when `alpha_0[0,:,:,:] >= 0` and `False` elsewhere

I think that my output from the loop should be similar to the example before looping. I couldn't find from where this is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `gaz` is defined as a numpy array of floats (default dtype for `np.zeros` function), while `gaz0` is a boolean mask computed when you define it, so, it contains booleans on it.

If you want `gaz0` to contain floats instead of booleans, you need to cast it as follows:

```py
gaz0 = gaz0.astype(np.float64)
```

Note that you can cast it to whatever dtype you need. Consider that True values are casted to 1 and False to zero.

This is exactly the rule being applied implicitly in your assignment:

```py
gaz[counter,:,:,:] = alpha_time[counter,:,:,:] >=0
```

In the second case, if you want to get booleans in your `gaz` numpy array, you just need to define with the proper dtype:

```py
gaz = numpy.zeros((time,11,12,13), dtype=bool)
```